# Given a sequence of N numbers ,extract number of sequences of length K having range less than R?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

There is an array of integers ,I have to find the number of sequences of K length having range (`max - min` of the subsequence) less than equal to R .Is there a relation between Number of sequences of length k and number of sequences of length K-1
?
I am trying to solve a practice question on SPOJ. I don't want the full solution,just point me in the right direction /suggestion/hint.

I was thinking of a deque like structure to maintain min and max elements of the array upto a certain index.However,when k is closer to n ,this would become close to o(n*n) which is too slow ,I am ideally looking at O(n) solution or O(n * log n) solution. It would be best if I can calculate the required value for K=1 to K=N using a recursion/iteration relation as the same answer maybe required again

Comment: Please post an example and define what do you mean by "range".

Comment: Range most likely means `max - min`.

Comment: @IVlad:sir you are correct ,range means max element -min element of the sequence selected

Comment: I don't have an answer, but it might be interesting to try to beat `O(N*N)` for an algorithm which just finds the number of qualifying ranges of length `K = N/2`.  And then maybe that could hint at an algorithm for the complete problem.

Comment: Can you please add a link to SPOJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect application for a deque. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598260/finding-consecutively-increasing-subsequence-stored-in-a-haphazard-manner/12598726#12598726).

You should be able to adapt that for your needs with almost no changes, giving you an `O(N)` solution.

Comment: :What if I have to calculate this value from K=1 to K=N ,what will be the complexity in that case.And what algorithm can I use ?

Comment: @user1724072 If you apply the same algorithm for each `K`, it will be `O(n^2)`, because the algorithm for a fixed `K` is `O(N)`. Do you want to count the number of substrings of length `1, 2, ..., N` with range `<= R`? That is a different question, I suggest you open another question for that problem.